# Measuring string and font width

Tags: java, string, swing, fonts, fontmetrics

I want to measure a "smallest unit" of a string (which is displayed in `JTextArea` with some font).

It's the width of a single character + the spacing after it (which depends on the next character).

Eg. I want to measure the pixel distance from beginning of char `A` to beginning of char `Z` in the string `"AZ"`.

How can I do that? I tried using the `FontMetrics` and measuring the string width of both characters together and then decrementing it for the width of the second one but it didn't work...

Comment: How did it not work? What did you get?

Comment: Can you post a code snippet?

Comment: FontMetrics should work, as Marko asked, what exactly did not work? Maybe you missed something.

Comment: `What I ended up with was bunch of letters glued one onto another whith no space inbetween, some of them even overlapped... Did I do something wrong?` - How do we know? Why do you think you need this information? You haven't told us what the requirement is. A JTextArea already paints the characters with spaces properly. So what exactly are you trying to do. You also haven't posted a `SSCCE` and I know you have been asked for a SSCCE in the past.

Comment: Gimme an hour, I'll post an SSCCE when I write it...

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java.awt.Font` has

```
public GlyphVector layoutGlyphVector(FontRenderContext frc,
                                     char[] text,
                                     int start,
                                     int limit,
                                     int flags) {
```

Then use `public Point2D getGlyphPosition(int glyphIndex)` method of `GlyphVector` and compare difference of `X` coordinates for any desired pair of chars.

Comment: Thank you, I've been looking for this forever!! :D